# git difftool doesn't open meld

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, meld

I have the below in my .gitconfig. For some reason `git difftool` doesn't open up meld. It only works with meld. I'm using Ubuntu.

How can I fix it so that meld is opened?

```
[diff]
        tool = meld [difftool]
    prompt = false [difftool "meld"]
    cmd = meld "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"

[merge]
    tool = meld [mergetool "meld"]
    cmd = meld "$LOCAL" "$MERGED" "$REMOTE" --output "$MERGED"
```